# Unix time javascript

Tags: javascript, unix, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

I am trying to return a formatted time from a unix time. The unix time is `1349964180`.

If you go to [unixtimestamp.com](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) and plug in `1349964180` for Timestamp you will get:

```
TIME STAMP: 1349964180

DATE (M/D/Y @ h:m:s): 10 / 11 / 12 @ 9:03:00am EST
```

This is what I want, but in javascript.

So something like:

```
function convert_time(UNIX_timestamp){
......
......
return correct_format;
}
```

and then the call:
`convert_time(1349964180);`

and console.log should print:
`10 / 11 / 12 @ 9:03:00am EST`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#highlighter_538397

Comment: maybe searching on stack overflow could have helped --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this

```
function convert_time(ts) {
   return new Date(ts * 1000) 
}
```

and call it like so

```
console.log(convert_time(1349964180));
```

Comment: Thu Oct 11 2012 10:32:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) <-- This is very close I just need the 9:03:00am EST  and not the GMT-0400

Comment: see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337327/find-current-time-in-et-est-or-edt-as-appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you need to multiply by 1000, because timestamps in JavaScript are measured in milliseconds.

Once you have that, you can just plug it into a `Date` object and return the formatted datetime. You will probably need a helper function to pad the numbers (`function pad(num) {return (num < 10 ? "0" : "")+num;}`) and you should use the `getUTC*()` functions to avoid timezone issues.

Answer (score 0):

A UNIX-timestamp is using seconds whereas JavaScript uses milliseconds. So, you have to multiply the value by `1000`:

```
var myDate  = new Date(1349964180 * 1000);
alert (myDate.toGMTString());
```