# Converting Unix time to "minutes ago" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, date, unix, time

I want to covert time() which PHP has created and stored in our database to minutes ago when it is captured by our JavaScript once requested by JSON.

http://media.queerdio.com/mobileDevice/?uri=nowplaying/1

as you can see we store time like

```
"airtime":1382526339
```

what we want to turn that to is

```
3 minutes ago
```

This is what we know.

We first would need to run something like this

```
function convert_time(ts) {
   return new Date(ts * 1000) 
}
```

Taking the airtime and running it through that function this makes it JavaScript compliant from what I read (I could be wrong) [Unix time javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842008/unix-time-javascript?lq=1)

Bt then I am not sure how to get it from JavaScript date time to minutes ago. We currently don't use jQuery and would be great if we could continue down that road, as this is the last issue I am having before I have finished coding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need for any dependency, just plain old javascript is sufficient. To convert a unix time stamp to a *"X time ago"*-like label, you simply use something like this:

```
function time2TimeAgo(ts) {
    // This function computes the delta between the
    // provided timestamp and the current time, then test
    // the delta for predefined ranges.

    var d=new Date();  // Gets the current time
    var nowTs = Math.floor(d.getTime()/1000); // getTime() returns milliseconds, and we need seconds, hence the Math.floor and division by 1000
    var seconds = nowTs-ts;

    // more that two days
    if (seconds > 2*24*3600) {
       return "a few days ago";
    }
    // a day
    if (seconds > 24*3600) {
       return "yesterday";
    }

    if (seconds > 3600) {
       return "a few hours ago";
    }
    if (seconds > 1800) {
       return "Half an hour ago";
    }
    if (seconds > 60) {
       return Math.floor(seconds/60) + " minutes ago";
    }
}
```

Of course you can change the texts/ranges as you see fit.

Hope this will help, my point is that you don't need to use any library to achieve this kind of things :)

Comment: perfect, Thank you so much simple and did not add 8.8kb to my script.

Comment: you're welcome, I will never understand people that love to add bloated libraries just because they're too lazy to think about a simple solution.

Comment: @sitifensys That's quite an interesting POV. My POV is that some people are just too lazy to look for a library that serves their needs and instead prefer to reinvent the wheel. I think that's also called the [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) phenomenon. The real costs of your approach in any aspect of the matter (QA, testing, extensibility, x-browser-compat, ...) will _never_ be covered by those 8.8k saved in terms of transfered data.

Comment: @mwhs Our two POVs are not incompatible. Mine is not a "systematically reinvent the wheel" but rather a "you should always keep it as simple as possible". While I do understand a developer going for a well tested and established framework to have a solid application foundation, I don't understand a guy adding *JQuery*+*JQueryUI*+*JQueryWhateverSuperCoolCandendarWidget* just to add a simple drop down calendar to a inputbox :).

Comment: @sitifensys I see you totally got my point. That is quite consistent with the motto "do less, write more" :-)

Comment: How to show hours ago if i pass this function unix timestamp?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) a small (8.8 kb minified) javascript library for formatting date objects. It works really well and has no further dependencies.

Comment: Try Moment.js with `moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();`

Comment: so do i put the unix time in moment(unixtime).startOf('hour').fromNow()

Comment: everything i put it it is getting returned as 33 minutes and the last two are being shown as two hours ago even knowing the last song was only 2 minutes ago

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this if you need more detail:

```js
function timeAgo(someDateInThePast) {
    var result = '';
    var difference = Date.now() - someDateInThePast;

    if (difference < 5 * 1000) {
        return 'just now';
    } else if (difference < 90 * 1000) {
        return 'moments ago';
    }

    //it has minutes
    if ((difference % 1000 * 3600) > 0) {
        if (Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 % 60) > 0) {
            let s = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 % 60) == 1 ? '' : 's';
            result = `${Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 % 60)} minute${s} `;
        }
    }

    //it has hours
    if ((difference % 1000 * 3600 * 60) > 0) {
        if (Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 % 24) > 0) {
            let s = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 % 24) == 1 ? '' : 's';
            result = `${Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 % 24)} hour${s}${result == '' ? '' : ','} ` + result;
        }
    }

    //it has days
    if ((difference % 1000 * 3600 * 60 * 24) > 0) {
        if (Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) > 0) {
            let s = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) == 1 ? '' : 's';
            result = `${Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)} day${s}${result == '' ? '' : ','} ` + result;
        }

    }

    return result + ' ago';
}

document.write(timeAgo(Date.parse('2019-10-10 13:10')));
```

https://github.com/carmatas/timeago

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/). It extends the browser its native Date object.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the last comment of Russell:

If you use Moment.js with a unix timestamp (epoch in seconds) then say

`moment.unix(unixtime).startOf('hour').fromNow()`

otherwise if you use a milliseconds timestamp (java `System.currentTimeMillis()`) then say

`moment(millis).startOf('hour').fromNow()`

See the documentation here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-offset/